# Trying to use classes in a switch statement

Tags: java, class, switch-statement

So I'm trying to write a program that does a handful of things, for example, it gives you a list of possible commands and if you type in '1' it should send you to a basic calculator application, however, I've run into a pickle that I can't seem to solve myself, I would appreciate your help

Here's the class Terminal I'm trying to call another class from:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Terminal {

    Scanner sc;

    public Terminal() {
        System.out.println("""
                *********************
                TERMINAL APPLICATION
                 Version 0.1 Beta
                      Retr0K
                *********************
                """);
        printCommands();
    }

    public void printCommands() {
        System.out.println("""
                ******************************************
                List of Commands:
                    0.) quit program
                    1.) basic math calculator
                    2.) temperature conversion calculator
                    3.) length conversion calculator
                    4.) quadratic formula calculator
                    5.) random number generator
                    6.) choose your own adventure game
                    7.) rock paper scissors game
                    8.) tic tak toe game
                ******************************************
                """);

        int command = getCommand(10);
        checkCommand(command);
    }

    public int getCommand(int options) {
        sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter a Corresponding Number (0-" + (options-1) + "): ");

        if(sc.hasNextInt()) {
            return sc.nextInt();
        }
        else {
            return -1;
        }
    }

    public void checkCommand(int command) {
        switch (command) {
            case 0 -> System.exit(0);
            case 1 -> new MathCalc();
            case 2 -> new TempCalc();
            case 3 -> new LengthConv();
            case 4 -> new QuadFormulaCalc();
            case 5 -> new RandNumGen();
            case 6 -> new ChooseAdventure();
            case 7 -> new RockPaperScissors();
            case 8 -> new TicTacToe();
            default -> {
                System.out.println("Invalid input, try again");
                printCommands();
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

The problem lies in this specific chunk of code:

```
public void checkCommand(int command) {
        switch (command) {
            case 0 -> System.exit(0);
            case 1 -> new MathCalc();
            case 2 -> new TempCalc();
            case 3 -> new LengthConv();
            case 4 -> new QuadFormulaCalc();
            case 5 -> new RandNumGen();
            case 6 -> new ChooseAdventure();
            case 7 -> new RockPaperScissors();
            case 8 -> new TicTacToe();
            default -> {
                System.out.println("Invalid input, try again");
                printCommands();
            }
        }
    }
```

Specifically when I try to input '1' to get to my MathCalc() class. Here's the code for the MathCalc() class if it helps:

```
public class MathCalc extends Terminal {

    public MathCalc() {
        System.out.println("""
                BASIC MATH CALCULATOR APP
                **************************
                """);

        printOperators();
    }

    public void printOperators() {
        System.out.println("""
                Operators:
                    0.) Return to previous screen
                    1.) addition
                    2.) subtraction
                    3.) multiplication
                    4.) division
                    5.) modulus
                """);

        int operator = getCommand(6);
        checkOperator(operator);
    }

    public void checkOperator(int operator) {
        switch (operator) {
            case 0 -> new Terminal();
            case 1 -> add();
            case 2 -> sub();
            case 3 -> mul();
            case 4 -> div();
            case 5 -> mod();
            default -> {
                System.out.println("Invalid Input, try again");
                printOperators();
            }
        }
    }

    public void add() {

    }

    public void sub() {

    }

    public void mul() {

    }

    public void div() {

    }

    public void mod() {

    }

}
```

It's not finished simply because I want to at least be able to access the stuff in the class before I work on it further.

Getting back to the problem, whenever I go to input '1', rather than sending me to my MathCalc() class, it seems to create a new Terminal class instead, here's what happens when I input 1 into my program:
[Output after inputting 1 into my program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zbrGz.png)

The strange thing, however, is that, when I type 1, and the previous stuff comes up, and then proceed to type 2 instead, both my TempConv() class and my MathCalc() class run, here's what that looks like:
[Output after inputting 1 and then 2 into my program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Fhjc.png)

Genuinely confused why this happens, would appreciate any help.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Alright, turns out I didn't realize that when you have a class extend another class like what I did:

```
public class MathCalc extends Terminal {...}
```

then, in this example, when you run MathCalc(), the stuff in the Terminal() class's constructor is also ran at the same time. I only wanted to extend Terminal because I had a method in terminal that would be the same for all my other classes, but I just copied and pasted instead and stopped extending Terminal and it works fine now.